# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNKeychainManager.SECURITY_LEVEL_ANY')

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

I am going to use the react-native-keychain lib in my RN project but seems to be not working on my local.

RN: 0.61.5

react-native-keychain: "6.1.1",

I tried to like this.

```
.......

const MEMORY_KEY_PREFIX = '@MyStorage:'
let dataMemory = {}

class MyStorage {
  static syncPromise = null

  static setItem(key, value) {
    Keychain.setGenericPassword(MEMORY_KEY_PREFIX + key, value)
    dataMemory[key] = value
    return dataMemory[key]
  }

  static getItem(key) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataMemory, key) ? dataMemory[key] : undefined
  }

  static removeItem(key) {
    Keychain.resetGenericPassword()
    return delete dataMemory[key]
  }

  static clear() {
    dataMemory = {}
    return dataMemory
  }
}
.......
```

But I am facing issues.

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNKeychainManager.SECURITY_LEVEL_ANY')

Is there any solution to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Same problem here ...

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried opening multiple iOS simulators. I am not sure if yours is the same case with the one I got.

For me the fix(?) was:

1. Close all iOS simulators
2. Run the react-native project specifically on a simulator.

   - `yarn ios --simulator="iphone 8"` - will run the app in iPhone 8
   - `yarn ios --simulator="iphone 11"` - will run the app in iPhone 11

To list all available device simulator you can run `xcrun simctl list devices`

PS: There is an issue in the package repo with similar error here which you might want to take a look at: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/221

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but not working for me. I used an android emulator and shows the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it:

Set in Podfile

```
pod 'RNKeychain', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-keychain'
```

or

```
use_native_modules!
```

And then run

```
pod install
```